# python3 Parser.setErrorHandler method missing

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to bail out of the parser upon first syntax error.
It seems that the `setErrorHandler` is not implemented? This is the error.

```
 parser.setErrorHandler(BailErrorStrategy())

AttributeError: 'XParser' object has no attribute 'setErrorHandler'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Python's Parser class](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Python3/src/antlr4/Parser.py) does not have a set-ter for this. Don't know why not.

Anyway, this is how you could set it:

```py
from antlr4.error.ErrorStrategy import BailErrorStrategy

...

parser = ...
parser._errHandler = BailErrorStrategy()
```